# How to submit guid as hidden form field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm assigning a GUID to a form field but it isn't being submitted with the form.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID=GuidToken" runat="server"/>
```

//psuedo code behind

```
GuidToken = [valid guid];
//check that guid successfully assigned - yes
```

Once the form is submitted, I extract all form values:

```
Request.Form["GuidToken"]
```

Other values come through fine but the above is null.  Is this something specific to the guid?

Comment: Your markup is not well-formed - can you correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But you might want to consider using a **session variable** to store and 'pass on' your token GUID to different pages?

```
Session["GuidToken"] = myGeneratedGUID;
```

and later

```
var retrievedGUID = Session["GuidToken"];
```

Be sure to check for NULL, Sessions can expire between POSTs.

Comment: I've decided to just pass it through the form URL since I don't want this living anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you were using `Request.Form`? You should use

```
Guid myGuid = Guid.Parse(GuidToken.Value);
```

If you still want to use Request.Form which I would not recommend, the name of the hidden field control has been changed by asp.net so the collection does not contain exactly what you specified because it has some autogenerated naming convention added to it. It now looks like this

```
Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$GuidToken"]
```

Debug mode

[image]

Comment: This is being submitted to a completely different aspx.  GuidToken and the autogenerated name you mention is not available.

Comment: If you are submitting from another .aspx file, the autogeneration still applies. stuffs are added to the control ID

Comment: But you are still using Request.Form[] in that case. Regardless, we're moving away from the original question.

Comment: inspect the request.Form in debug mode placing your mouse on the AllKeys property and see what values were passed

Comment: The Key is there.  It just doesn't have an associated value.